# Acquiring multiple locks atomically in java

Tags: java, locking, deadlock, synchronized

I have the following code:
Note: I simplified the code as much as possible for readability.
If I forgot any critical pieces let me know.

```
public class User(){

    private Relations relations;

    public User(){
        relations = new Relations(this);
    }   

    public getRelations(){
        return relations;
    }
}


public class Relations(){

    private User user;

    public Relations(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    public synchronized void setRelation(User user2){
        Relations relations2 = user2.getRelations();

        synchronized(relations2){

            storeRelation(user2);

            if(!relations2.hasRelation(user))
                relations2.setRelation(user);
        }
    }   

    public synchronized boolean hasRelation(User user2){
        ... // Checks if this relation is present in some kind of collection
    }

    /*Store this relation, unless it is already present*/
    private void storeRelation(User user2){
        ... // Stores this relation in some kind of collection
    }
}
```

This implementation should make sure that for all Relations x, y with:

```
x.user = u_x
y.user = u_y
```

the following invariant holds:

```
x.hasRelation( u_y ) <=> y.hasRelation( u_x )
```

I believe that holds for the code stated above?

Note: It does of course not hold during the execution of setRelation(..),
but at that moment the locks for both relations involved are 
held by the executing thread so no other thread can read the
hasRelation(..) of one of the relations involved.

Assuming that this holds i believe there is still a potential deadlock-risk.
Is that correct? And if it is, how can I solve it?
I think i would need to obtain both locks in setRelation(..) atomically somehow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct on both points: your invariant does hold (assuming that I understand correctly what your method-names mean and so on, and assuming that by `if(!relations.hasRelation(user)) relations2.setRelation(user2);` you meant to write `if(!relations2.hasRelation(user)) relations2.setRelation(user);`), but you do have the risk of a deadlock: if one thread needs to obtain a lock on `x` and then on `y`, and another thread needs to obtain a lock on `y` and then on `x`, then there's a risk that each thread will succeed in getting its *first* lock, and thereby prevent the other from getting its *second* lock.

One solution is to enforce a strict universal ordering for getting locks on `Relations` instances. What you do is, you add a constant integer field `lockOrder`:

```
private final int lockOrder;
```

and a static integer field `currentLockOrder`:

```
private static int currentLockOrder = 0;
```

and every time you create a `Relations` instance, you set its `lockOrder` to the current value of `currentLockOrder`, and increment said:

```
public Relations()
{
    synchronized(Relations.class) // a lock on currentLockOrder
    {
        lockOrder = currentLockOrder;
        ++currentLockOrder;
    }
}
```

such that every instance of `Relations` will have a distinct, immutable value for `lockOrder`. Your `setRelation` method would then obtain locks in the specified order:

```
public void setRelation(final User thatUser)
{
    final Relations that = thatUser.getRelations();

    synchronized(lockOrder < that.lockOrder ? this : that)
    {
        synchronized(lockOrder < that.lockOrder ? that : this)
        {
            storeRelation(thatUser);

            if(! that.hasRelation(user))
                that.storeRelation(user);
        }
    }
}
```

thereby ensuring that if two threads both need to get locks on both `x` and `y`, then either they'll both first get locks on `x`, or they'll both first get locks on `y`. Either way, no deadlock will occur.

Note, by the way, that I changed `setRelation` to `storeRelation`. `setRelation` would work, but why add that complexity?

Also, there's still one thing I don't get: how come `x.setRelation(u_y)` calls `x.storeRelation(u_y)` *unconditionally*, but calls `y.setRelation(u_x)` (or `y.storeRelation(u_x)`) only if `y` doesn't already have the relationship? It doesn't make sense. It seems like either *both* checks are needed, or *neither* check is. (Without seeing the implementation of `Relations.storeRelation(...)`, I can't guess which of those is the case.)

Comment: Updated the first part of your answer (which was indeed a typo), reading up on the rest.

Comment: That seems to solve my problem completely! Considering your last comment: my implementation of storeRelation is a Set, so an extra check would not be necessary. I will do another update on that. Thanks for the feedback. Just one more issue: Is this strategy applicable to more then 2 locks? It seems limited to a symmetric problem with 2 locks, correct?

Comment: @Antiz: It's directly applicable to any fixed number of locks: if you need to lock 20 instances, then you can put them in a list, sort that list by `lockOrder`, and then nest 20 `synchronized` blocks one inside the next, in that order. It's almost-as-directly applicable to any *bounded* number of locks: if you need to lock *up to 20* instances, then you can use the same approach, just padding the list with duplicates. (In Java, it's safe for a thread to have multiple nested `synchronize`s on a single object.) But if you have a potentially *unbounded* number of locks, then *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* you have to put in a bit more effort. The concept will still be the same -- always grab locks in a consistent order, so that no two threads can ever each hold a lock that the other needs -- but you can't just conveniently nest your `synchronized` blocks anymore. You'd need to either use recursion (which is the closest you can come to getting arbitrarily many `synchronize`-locks in a "loop"), or to use a non-language-syntax approach, such as [`ReentrantLock`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

Comment: If you can't have a unique ordering, I think the alternative is to have a lock that prevents other threads from taking out a lock. You need to release the "meta lock" if you can't acquire the normal locks.

Comment: Turns out this was worked out 50 years ago https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem

Comment: @Boris: I can't quite picture your proposal (it doesn't seem compatible with how `synchronized` works), but fortunately, I *also* can't quite picture a situation where "you can't have a unique ordering", so I don't think such a proposal is needed (which is good, because it would create a lot more cross-thread contention).