# Java - using wait() and notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF [Java, Multithreading with synchronized methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526460/java-multithreading-with-synchronized-methods)... he didn't ask the same question.

I am trying to write a program that using multi-threading and deadlocks. I am having trouble understanding how and where to use wait() and notify() in my synchronized methods to have the thread wait and wake it up with notify(). I have it to make the first thread wait after the ping statement so the next thread will start it's ping statement too.  But I have a notify() to wake up the first thread and I can't figure out why the thread will not wake up. The following is suppose to be my output:

```
Starting...1
Girl (ping): pinging Boy
Boy (ping): pinging Girl
Girl (ping): asking Boy to confirm
Boy (confirm): confirm to Girl
Girl (ping): got confirmation
Boy (ping): asking Girl to confirm
Girl (confirm): confirm to Boy
Boy (ping): got confirmation
```

My code is deadlocking or I am not using wait and notify correctly because it stops here:

```
Starting...1
Girl (ping): pinging Boy
Boy (ping): pinging Girl
Girl (ping): asking Boy to confirm
Boy (confirm): confirm to Girl
Girl (ping): got confirmation
```

Here is my code:

Monitor.java

```
class Monitor {
String name;

   public Monitor (String name) { this.name = name; }

   public String getName() {  return this.name; }

   public synchronized void ping (Monitor p) {
      p.release(p);
      System.out.println(this.name + " (ping): pinging " + p.getName());
      notify();
      try { wait(); } catch (Exception e) {}
      System.out.println(this.name + " (ping): asking " + p.getName() + " to confirm");
      p.confirm(p);
      System.out.println(this.name + " (ping): got confirmation");
   }

   public synchronized void confirm (Monitor p) {
      System.out.println(this.name + " (confirm): confirm to " + p.getName());
   }

   public synchronized void release (Monitor p) {
      notify();
   }
}
```

Runner.java

```
public class Runner extends Thread {
Monitor m1, m2;

    public Runner (Monitor m1, Monitor m2) { 
      this.m1 = m1; 
      this.m2 = m2; 
    }

    public void run () {  
       m1.ping(m2);  
    }
}
```

Deadlock.java

```
public class DeadLock {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
      int i=1;
      System.out.println("Starting..."+(i++));
      Monitor a = new Monitor("Girl");
      Monitor b = new Monitor("Boy");
      (new Runner(a, b)).start();
      (new Runner(b, a)).start();
   }
}
```

Comment: A `deadlock` is that the program (or at least some threads) stop running because each of them is waiting for the other to release resources. Are you sure that you mean that you want your program to have deadlocks?

Comment: No I do not want it to deadlock sorry if I was a little wordy. I am trying to have no deadlocks and get the threads to wait and wake up using notify to get my desired output.

Comment: The code is strange... I mean, in `ping` you `this.notify()` (which has no effect since the thread is not waiting) and then `this.wait()` which stops the thread. The other thread would just the same, so both threads end up waiting for the other to wake. Are you sure the first line isn't `synchronized (p) {p.notify();}`. The `wait` should be inside the synchronized block, if I am right (a little too sleepy right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling:

```
(new Runner(a, b)).start();
// which effectively calls in run()
a.ping(b);
```

This locks `a` calls notify on `a` and then waits on `a`.

The other thread calls:

```
(new Runner(b, a)).start();
// which effectively calls in run()
b.ping(a);
```

This locks `b` calls notify on `b` and then waits on `b`.

Since neither of the threads is notifying the other one, they will never leave that state.  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish so it's hard to figure out how to fix the code.

**Edit:**

Now that you've edited your code you have a more standard deadlock.

- The first thread locks `a` then tries to lock `b` to notify it.
- The second thread locks `b` then tries to lock `a` to notify it.

Each thread has their lock but needs the other lock to continue.  Classic deadlock.

I suggest that you learn to use the debugger @OhioState22. Set break points and step through your code. Here's a decent [Eclipse tutorial](http://vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

Comment: I am trying to get the code to be my output listed above. I have modified the above code a little trying to get the threads to work and was able to get it to print out to where the girl gets the confirmation. How can I now get the Boy to confirm the Girl?

Comment: I've edited my answer.  You've got to do some work on your own.  You can't just keep editing your answer until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule avoid using Java's wait() and notify() and prefer one of Java 5's concurrency features instead, e.g. ReentrantLock. The reason is that if a thread calls notify() before your thread hits wait(), the subsequent call to wait() will block and depending on your algorithm, indefinitely. Lookup the javadocs  for [RenetrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)